# One C++ client fails to load with our new COM registered .NET .dll, another works

Tags: c++, .net, com, regsvr32, regasm

We have an old C/C++ .dll that a customer accesses via COM.

We have tried to replace our old .dll with a new one written i .NET.

Customer cannot recompile their client so it is important that the old .dll can be replaced simply by COM unregister / register new (using regsvr32 / regasm).

We believe we have built the .NET .dll with the same COM interface as the old; GUID's, names, dispid's etc. all match. We have verified this by writing our own C++ test application and it continues to work when we unregister old .dll / register new one.

The problem is that the customer's client failes to start.

Strangely if we leave the old .dll registered (e.g. both .dll's are registerd) it works; The customer's application starts and calls methods in our new .dll. But as soon as we unregister the old .dll the application fails to start again.

We have tried different ways to register the new .dll; using regasm with /codebase option, /tbl, etc.

If I inspect with OLE/COM Viewer I can see some minor differences between new and old .dll, for example the type library "name" differs. But I suppose since our own C++ test client works with either .dll the COM interfaces are enough similar?

Please, anyone has any idea? How is it possible for one C++ client to load with our new .dll while another fails? Why do both work if we leave the old .dll registered in parallel to the new one? Is there any explanation why the two C++ clients behave differently?

---

UPDATE: 
The error message in the client says:

### "failed when running: CLSIDFromProgID. Check if [myDll].dll is registered."

Kind Regards P.T

Comment: you might try running sysinternals regmon (procmon?) during the register/unregister calls for both dlls. This might throw up any difference in the registry keys created/destroyed between the two.

Comment: I checked registry before and after and it seems ProgId was different. I fixed it but it didn't help. There are also other things i registry that are different for example "VersionIndependentProgId", "TypeLib" and "ThreadingModel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities. First, ensure you are registering the type library of your new DLL. The old one may be doing it as part of DllRegisterServer, but AFAIK, .Net DLLs do not. Register it with REGTLB.exe.

Also check the threading models are the same in both DLLs.

If neither of those help, I suggest you keep on until OLEVIEW says they are identical - you never know what the client is doing which is different from yours.

Comment: I managed to get the error message from the client: "failed when running: CLSIDFromProgID. Check if [myDll].dll is registered.". Seems something is wrong in the registry? I changed ProgId to match but it didn't help. However I notice that in registry ThreadingModel says "Appartment" for the old .dll and "Both" for my new.

Comment: @Poppert, make them ALL the same, including ThreadingModel, TypeLib etc. Also can you confirm when you changed the ProgID that the message changed or not? Also did you confirm the progID was updated in the registry correctly or not?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No, the message is the same. Yes i verified ProgId was updated. If it's not too much, can you point me in any direction on how to change ThreadingModel, TypeLib and VersionIndependentProgId? I suppose I must change this in code / attributes like with ProgId?

Comment: @Poppert, you need to make EVERYTHING the same. Just go in with registry editor and change them to match (or use a .REG file). Then you will know whether that is what made the difference. (Probably VersionIndpendantProgID since that is what is generally used when creating by progid).

Comment: Ah, ok, so it is enough to simply change directly in the Registry? Thanks, will try that!

Comment: Generally there is more than one ProgID, each with the samve VersionIndependentProgID and the same clsid. You don't know which name they are using so you need to make sure they are all present. Or use Sysinternals ProcessMonitor (procmon) to monitor registry access, which will show you.

Comment: Ben, thank you very much! We were able to get everything to work by manually editing the registry and adding VersionIndependentProgID.